# Mercurial - generate patch for both committed and uncommitted changes combined

Tags: mercurial

Sometimes in development it is useful for me to see a diff for both committed changes and uncommitted changes combined.

eg, as though they were either both uncommitted and I used `hg diff`,
or both uncommitted and I used `hg diff -c REV`.

Is there a way to do that?  I have tried variants of diff, export and log.

Answer (score 1):

For this toy-repo in such state

```
>hg st
M a.txt
>hg log --style compact
1[tip]   4d554db9595b   2016-08-05 23:56 +0500   lazybadger
  Change 1

0   8bc9bcf8b736   2016-08-05 23:55 +0500   lazybadger
  Initial state
```

combined diff for `4d554db9595b`

```
>hg diff -c 1
diff -r 8bc9bcf8b736 -r 4d554db9595b a.txt
--- a/a.txt     Fri Aug 05 23:55:46 2016 +0500
+++ b/a.txt     Fri Aug 05 23:56:19 2016 +0500
@@ -1,1 +1,2 @@
 Line 1
+Line 2
```

and workdir

```
>hg diff
diff -r 4d554db9595b a.txt
--- a/a.txt     Fri Aug 05 23:56:19 2016 +0500
+++ b/a.txt     Fri Aug 05 23:57:59 2016 +0500
@@ -1,2 +1,3 @@
 Line 1
 Line 2
+Line 3
```

will be, obviously

```
>hg diff -r "parents(1)"
diff -r 8bc9bcf8b736 a.txt
--- a/a.txt     Fri Aug 05 23:55:46 2016 +0500
+++ b/a.txt     Sat Aug 06 00:06:20 2016 +0500
@@ -1,1 +1,3 @@
 Line 1
+Line 2
+Line 3
```

PS: Just some fast-reading of `hg help diff`, nothing more harder... use brain, at last!